# Save directly to SharePoint Online from a website

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to save directly to SharePoint Online from a website?

For example, if I'm on a website and I find a file to download, I **right-click** > **Save As**, if I paste a SharePoint document library URL into the **File name** dialog, I receive an Access Denied error (even though I have access to that document library).  The full error I receive is:

> Access Denied.  Before opening files in this location, you must first
> add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the website,
> and select the option to login automatically.

I have added `<redacted>.sharepoint.com` to my Trusted Sites list and this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could map a network drive to a SharePoint library.

Reference: [Map a network drive to a SharePoint library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53)

Then, save file into the mapping network drive.

Comment: A statement in that article reads: _Before you start, it's important to note that this is legacy technology and it may be affected by the deprecation of Internet Explorer in August 2021 (see Microsoft 365 apps and services to end support for IE 11)._